# Object arraylist initialization in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an object called `Carriage`. When I initialize it I have to send a number of seats to the constructor:

```
Carriage newCarriage = new Carriage(30); //30=num of seats
```

Now I created a new class called `Train`, and this is its constructor:

```
public class Train {
    ArrayList<Carriage> trainCarriageList;

    Train(int baseTrainSize,int baseCarriageSize){
        trainCarriageList= new ArrayList<Carriage>(baseTrainSize);
    }
}
```

Now the question is: How do I initiate a train arraylist with the size of "baseTrainSize" and each `Carriage` with the size of baseCarriageSize correctly?

Comment: [Use a loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: What have you tried? You need to fill ``trainCarriageList`` with instances of ``Carriage``.

Comment: you cannot initialise arraylist with specific size. it will add as much as object you want.

Comment: `List<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<Train>(baseTrainSize);`.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Of course you can. That is the purpose of the constructor, see the documentation.
@LuiggiMendoza This fills the list with the very same instance of ``Train`` (which is called ``Carriage`` btw), that is not the desired result.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: then you will have a `trainList` that contains multiple reference to the same `Train` which is not what he wants I suppose.

Comment: @Jack true, don't know what was I thinking. Comment fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass the size (x) to the constructor of an `ArrayList` you **DON'T** initialize it with x new elements, you initialize it with exactly 0 elements. The capacity is x. The inner implementation of `ArrayList` is a regular array which will start with size **x**. When the array is filled, the array list initializes a new array of size 2x and copies the array of size x to it. This is a costly step. By declaring the size, you can spare this step if you know exactly how many elements will be in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: thanks, but what about the seat size, i have to initial it because it i created a constructor that gets the size of the seats

Comment: Please read my answer again. Your problem is the lack of understanding on how `ArrayList` works

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop for that. But logically speaking, just looping to add elements all initialized with the same value does not make sense to me. Rather add one more constructor to have the default value , whatever you need. Although if you really need to do that then do something like this:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < baseTrainSize; i++) {
Carriage carriage = new Carriage(30);
trainCarriageList.add(carriage);
}
```

Comment: The upper loop limit should be ``baseTrainSize``, not ``baseCarriageSize``. Line 2 should be ``new Carriage(baseCarriageSize)``, not ``new Carriage(30)``.

Comment: but to do it in the constructor?

Comment: i mean the train constructor

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList<Carriage>` does not contain any `Carriage` until you don't add them to the collection.

This means that you shouldn't care about initialising how many seats a Carriage has when you initialise the container for them but just when you initialise them.

```
trainCarriageList = new ArrayList<Carriage>(baseTrainSize);
...
Carriage carriage = new Carriage(30);
trainCarriageList.add(carriage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have `Class Train` implement List. This way, your train object would literally be a list of `Carriage`s.

Comment: That would mean he has to implement all the methods that the ``List`` interface declares. All 25 of them. In this case, aggregation is clearly more useful than inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public class Train {
  ArrayList<Carriage> trainCarriageList;

  Train(int baseTrainSize,int baseCarriageSize){
    // initialize the List with the base size:
    trainCarriageList= new ArrayList<Carriage>(baseTrainSize);
    // initialize each list element with it's own base size:
    for(int i=0;i<baseTrainSize;i++){
      trainCarriageList.set(i, new Carriage(baseCarriageSize));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Accept this as the answer then, use the checkbox on the left.